# Why is dictionary ordering non-deterministic?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, python-3.3, non-deterministic

I recently switched from Python 2.7 to Python 3.3, and it seems that while in Python 2 the ordering of dictionary keys was arbitrary but consistent, in Python 3 the ordering of the keys of a dictionary obtained with e.g. [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) appears non-deterministic.

If I run:

```
class Test(object): pass
parameters = vars(Test)
print(list(parameters.keys()))
```

in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3, then:

- Python 2.7 consistently gives me

  ```
  ['__dict__', '__module__', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
  ```
- With Python 3.3, I can get any random order – for example:

  ```
  ['__weakref__', '__module__', '__qualname__', '__doc__', '__dict__']
  ['__doc__', '__dict__', '__qualname__', '__module__', '__weakref__']
  ['__dict__', '__module__', '__qualname__', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
  ['__weakref__', '__doc__', '__qualname__', '__dict__', '__module__']
  ```

Where does this non-determinism come from? And why is something like

```
list({str(i): i for i in range(10)}.keys())
```

… consistent between runs, always giving

```
['3', '2', '1', '0', '7', '6', '5', '4', '9', '8']
```

… ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

---

**Update:** In Python 3.6, `dict` has a [new implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict) which preserves insertion order. From Python 3.7, this order-preserving behaviour is [guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html):

> the insertion-order preservation nature of [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) objects [has been declared](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) to be an official part of the Python language spec.

---

This is the result of a [security fix](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2012-March/009394.html) from 2012, which was [enabled by default](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) in Python 3.3 (scroll down to "Security improvements").

From the announcement:

> Hash randomization causes the iteration order of dicts and sets to be
>   unpredictable and differ across Python runs. Python has never guaranteed
>   iteration order of keys in a dict or set, and applications are advised to never
>   rely on it. Historically, dict iteration order has not changed very often across
>   releases and has always remained consistent between successive executions of
>   Python. Thus, some existing applications may be relying on dict or set ordering.
>   Because of this and the fact that many Python applications which don't accept
>   untrusted input are not vulnerable to this attack, in all stable Python releases
>   mentioned here, HASH RANDOMIZATION IS DISABLED BY DEFAULT.

As noted above, the last, capitalized bit is no longer true in Python 3.3.

**See also:** [`object.__hash__()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) ("Note" sidebar).

If absolutely necessary, you can disable hash randomization in versions of Python affected by this behaviour by setting the [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) environment variable to `0`.

---

Your counterexample:

```
list({str(i): i for i in range(10)}.keys())
```

… does *not* in fact always give the same result in Python 3.3, although the number of different orderings is limited [due to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26136894/1014938) the way hash collisions are handled:

```
$ for x in {0..999}
> do
>   python3.3 -c "print(list({str(i): i for i in range(10)}.keys()))"
> done | sort | uniq -c
     61 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
     73 ['1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8']
     62 ['2', '3', '0', '1', '6', '7', '4', '5', '8', '9']
     59 ['3', '2', '1', '0', '7', '6', '5', '4', '9', '8']
     58 ['4', '5', '6', '7', '0', '1', '2', '3', '8', '9']
     55 ['5', '4', '7', '6', '1', '0', '3', '2', '9', '8']
     62 ['6', '7', '4', '5', '2', '3', '0', '1', '8', '9']
     63 ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0', '9', '8']
     60 ['8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
     66 ['8', '9', '2', '3', '0', '1', '6', '7', '4', '5']
     65 ['8', '9', '4', '5', '6', '7', '0', '1', '2', '3']
     53 ['8', '9', '6', '7', '4', '5', '2', '3', '0', '1']
     62 ['9', '8', '1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6']
     52 ['9', '8', '3', '2', '1', '0', '7', '6', '5', '4']
     73 ['9', '8', '5', '4', '7', '6', '1', '0', '3', '2']
     76 ['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
```

As noted at the beginning of this answer, that's no longer the case in Python 3.6:

```
$ for x in {0..999}
> do
>   python3.6 -c "print(list({str(i): i for i in range(10)}.keys()))"
> done | sort | uniq -c
   1000 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: So why does this not apply to something like `{str(i): i for i in range(10)}`?

Comment: So how do we disable this randomization?

Comment: @nmz787 https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED

Answer (score 14):

Note that Python 3.7 still has non-deterministic sets however. dicts preserve insertion order but sets do not. Sets can exhibit the same random behavior.

`python3 -c "print({str(i) for i in range(9)})"`

still gives different results from one run to the next.

Comment: Came here to post an answer because I found this out the hard way... then I saw this one... +1