# Estrange behavior reading JSON files in Python 3.3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am using the 'json' packages to read JSON files and convert to CSV. I wrote a script some months ago using Python 2.7, which extracts a dictionary containing the name of the objects in JSON file **(It worked perfectly back then).**
 When I run the script in Python 3.3 the order in which the objects are retrieved are different every time the script is executed.

*Any idea why this happens? and How to fix it?*

My script:

```
import json
import csv

   input_file = open('my_path\\json_file', 'r')
   myjson = json.load(input_f)
   input_f.close()
   new_json = myjson['markers'] #main object containing sub-objects

   keys = {} #empty dictionary to store list of sub-objects

   for i in new_json:
       for k in i.keys():
           keys[k] = 1
```

Some output examples:

EXECUTION 1:

```
KEYS{'': 1, 'latitude': 1, 'Particles': 1, 'Wind Speed': 1, 'image': 1, 'Humidity': 1, 'C/ Daoiz y Velarde': 1, 'Noise': 1, 'Battery level': 1, 'id': 1, 'Soil Moisture': 1, ....}
```

EXECUTION 2:

```
KEYS{'': 1, 'Relative humidity': 1, 'N02': 1, 'Particles': 1, 'Rainfall': 1, 'image': 1, 'Odometer': 1, 'Co Index': 1, 'Wind Direction': 1, 'Atmospheric Pressure': 1, ....}
```

Comment: Python's `dict` objects are unordered. The top answer in the question I linked to above will solve this by loading the json directly into a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: OT: Can I ask you why you are exporting data from JSON to CSV? In other words what is the end goal you want to achieve by this transformation?

Comment: My end goal is to prepare data harvested from a website into PostgreSQL. Ordering and cleaning (remove some known inconsistencies) is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way dictionaries now work in Python 3. It is the result of a security patch that was disabled by default in 2.x. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959001/65529) for more explanation.

You can get the behavior you desire by using the `object_pairs_hook` keyword argument. Pass it the `collections.OrderedDict` class. You'll likely also want to store the results in an OrderedDict, too. This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#json.load) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects). For example:

```
import json
import csv
import collections

input_file = open('my_path\\json_file', 'r')
myjson = json.load(input_f, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
input_f.close()
new_json = myjson['markers'] #main object containing sub-objects

keys = collections.OrderedDict()

for i in new_json:
    for k in i.keys():
        keys[k] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because python dictionaries are **not** guaranteed to be sorted. Use an ordereddict to fix it:

```
import json
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

input_file = open('my_path\\json_file, 'r')
myjson = OrderedDict(json.load(input_f))
input_f.close()
keys = {} #empty dictionary to store list of sub-objects

for i in new_json:
    for k in i.keys():
       keys[k] = 1
```

Comment: I don't think this will preserve the ordering that's in the file stored on disk, because it's still initially being loaded into a normal `dict`.

Comment: OP wants it formatted on output if he wants it on the disk, they need only write it out that way, using json.dumps or whatever.