# How get expected order in result dictionary?

Tags: python

```
result = {}
a = ["a","b","c"]
b = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(3):
  result[a[i]] = b[i]

print result
```

I expect to get following result: `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`

But the real one is `{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}`

What is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: `dictionaries` are not ordered in python. Use `OrderedDict` https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 5):

A python dictionary has an internal order that is randomized and that you shouldn't depend on.

If you would like to retain the order that you inserted objects in, you should use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 2):

`dict`s are unordered because keys aren't compared, their hashes are.

Use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) from the `collections` module to maintain the order you inputted.

```
>>> import collections
>>>
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> result = collections.OrderedDict(zip(a, b))
>>> result
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> dict(result) # no longer ordered
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: In the latest versions of python, it's actually even more complicated than using just the hash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956313/dictionary-ordering-non-deterministic-in-python3