# Why the output is not logically correct?

Tags: python

In the following code.

```
>>> hash('bar')
327024216814240868
>>> hash('baz')
327024216814240876
>>> hash('bar') % 8
4
>>> hash('baz') % 8
4
```

`bar` and `baz`, however, have hash values that are exactly 8 apart and thus map to the exact same slot, `4`:

Their order now depends on which key was slotted first; the second key will have to be moved to a next slot:

```
>>> {'baz': None, 'bar': None}
{'bar': None, 'baz': None}
>>> {'bar': None, 'baz': None}
{'baz': None, 'bar': None}
```

But here both the outputs must be same as hash value of `bar` comes before than `baz`.
I meant,

```
>>>{'bar': None, 'baz': None}
```

should come,

```
{'bar': None, 'baz': None}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956313/dictionary-ordering-non-deterministic-in-python3 , this will help.

Comment: You're making a lot of assumption on how a dictionary in python works, is this founded in anything in particular, and for what version of python, or are you just guessing ?

Comment: Could you please take some pain to explain it? I don't get it.

Comment: @nos I'm not guessing, it's the output which is coming, I'm using Python 2.7.10

Comment: @ashishverma I'm asking why you do %8, why not %2 ? or anything else ? Why do you assume the existing key should be moved, instead of the new key ?

Comment: @nos ok, you're right, but I want to know, dict prints randomly but it also has a pattern which is decided by the ordering of slots, ie., first it prints slot 1 then slot 2 and so on but if bar is lying in a slot which comes before baz then why bar is not printing first?

Comment: @nos, even if I don't %8 the hash value of `bar` is less than `baz`, which means `bar` is in a slot which comes before `baz`

Comment: Maybe look at the [source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Objects/dictobject.c#L687). There is stated, that it doesn't always use the key-hash

Comment: Getting deja vu. I think you asked this exact question yesterday and it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

From Python version security release https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2012-March/009394.html

Hash randomization causes the iteration order of dicts and sets to be
unpredictable and differ across Python runs. Python has never guaranteed
iteration order of keys in a dict or set, and applications are advised to never
rely on it. Historically, dict iteration order has not changed very often across
releases and has always remained consistent between successive executions of
Python. Thus, some existing applications may be relying on dict or set ordering.
Because of this and the fact that many Python applications which don't accept
untrusted input are not vulnerable to this attack, in all stable Python releases
mentioned here, ***hash randomization is disabled by default***. There are two ways to
enable it. The -R commandline option can be passed to the python executable. It
can also be enabled by setting an environmental variable ***pythonhashseed*** to
"random". (Other values are accepted, too; pass -h to python for complete
description.)

Comment: I want to know, dict prints randomly but it also has a pattern which is decided by the ordering of slots, ie., first it prints slot 1 then slot 2 and so on but if `bar` is lying in a slot which comes before `baz` then why `bar` is not printing first?

Comment: Python has never guaranteed iteration order of keys in a dict or set, and applications are advised to never rely on it. What i undstand on my side may be at Hash table they put any random function to pick up keys.

Comment: Ashis perhaps you want to use something like ordering dict?