# Python Linear Search Ordering change

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to do a linear search on a csv file and have written a simple algorithm to do so. It should print the amount of lines searched and the information

```
 import csv
 count = 1
 with open('UKDATA.csv') as csvfile: #This opens the file as a csv file
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
     for row in reader:              
        first_name = row["first_name"]
        last_name = row["last_name"]
        if first_name == "Alethea" and last_name == "Mould" :
            print(count, "rows searched")
            print("Alethea Mould found on line",count+1)
            print(row)
            break
        count += 1
```

Everytime I run this code it print out the information in a different order.
Why does it do this
Thanks

Comment: "print out the information in a different order" - wat?

Comment: it prints all of the fields out in a different order everytime I run the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionary ordering non-deterministic in python3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956313/dictionary-ordering-non-deterministic-in-python3)

Comment: Ok, so this has nothing to do with CSV or linear searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you mean that it prints out the row fields in a different order during the statement

```
print(row)
```

Why?  You have created `reader` as a `DictReader` meaning that it returns each line as a **dictionary**.  Dictionaries do not promise any ordering of keys.

If you wish it to be printed in a correct order, then you may use something like:

```
print([row[k] for k in reader.fieldnames])
```