# Use .join() to manipulate inner dictionary elements of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, join, python-2.x

I have a question. I tried to put together information from other questions but with no success.
Assume I have data in the following format:

```
file_list = ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
inner_dict = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}
outer_dict = {}

for f in file_list:
     outer_dict[f] = inner_dict
```

My aim is to print (to be saved into a file) in the following way:

```
f1, 1, one
f1, 2, two
f1, 3, three
f2, 1, one
f2, 2, two
f2, 3, three
f3, 1, one
f3, 2, two
f3, 3, three
```

To this aim, I started focusing on the items of `outer_dict`, and I managed to print them separately, but I am not sure how to further join (and, more importantly, if this is the most direct way to go).

```
for key, value in outer_dict.items():
    inn_keys = value.keys()
    inn_values = value.values()
    b1 = "\n".join([str(x) for x in inn_keys] )
    b2 = "\n".join([str(x) for x in inn_values] )
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string_list = []

for el1 in file_list:
    for el2 in inner_dict.items():
        string_list.append(", ".join([el1, str(el2[0]), el2[1]]))

print(string_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['f1, 1, one', 
 'f1, 2, two', 
 'f1, 3, three', 
 'f2, 1, one', 
 'f2, 2, two', 
 'f2, 3, three', 
 'f3, 1, one', 
 'f3, 2, two',
 'f3, 3, three']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I would need to print as I posted in the question, (so 3 values per row separated by a comma) as I would like to save each row in a csv file.

Comment: Also I would take the chance to understand how .join() works in this specific example.

Comment: `"separator".join(iterable)` joins the strings of the passed in `iterable` using the `separator` string.

Comment: The final output is not what I would need, check out the initial question, thanks, S. (basically I need the outer key "repeated" for all the respective items).

Answer (score 2):

Patching your code to work will look something like this:

```
b1 = ""
for key, value in outer_dict.items():
    b1 += "\n".join([','.join([key,str(k),v]) for k, v in value.items()]) + '\n'
```

**But**, I think you did it way more complicated than it should be in python, a much simpler solution will be using nested loops:

```
s = ""
for f in file_list:
    for k,v in inner_dict.items():
        s+= ','.join([f,str(k),v]) + "\n"
```

I'm sure you can figure out a one-liner that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Double [**`join`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) can be used in your case, remember to convert your **`ints`** to **`str`**:

```
print '\n'.join([', '.join([e1] + [str(e) for e in e2]) for e1, e2 in zip(file_list, inner_dict.items())])

f1, 1, one
f2, 2, two
f3, 3, three
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this oneliner- just concatenate tuples (i.e. `[(i,)+j for j in inner_dict.items() for i in file_list]`) and flatten the list of tuples into a simple list.

```
[item for sublist in [(i,)+j for j in inner_dict.items() for i in file_list] for item in sublist]
```

Output-

```
['f1', 1, 'one', 'f2', 1, 'one', 'f3', 1, 'one', 'f1', 2, 'two', 'f2', 2, 'two', 'f3', 2, 'two', 'f1', 3, 'three', 'f2', 3, 'three', 'f3', 3, 'three']
```

N.B. Better to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in case of maintaining order using dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the other answers assume a deterministic order in the dictionary. But dictionaries [do not have a deterministic order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). In fact, you can set `hash_randomization` in Python 2. Just start with the command line option `-R`:

```
python -R
```

This is the [default in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956313/dictionary-ordering-non-deterministic-in-python3).

So to make this work more reliably and also with Python 3, sort the keys of the inner dictionary. Since it is used many times, sort it only once and re-use it in all iterations over the file list:

```
from __future__ import print_function

file_list = ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
inner_dict = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}

inner_list = [', '.join([str(key), inner_dict[key]]) for key in sorted(inner_dict)]

for fname in file_list:
    for inner in inner_list:
        print('{}, {}'.format(fname, inner))
```

Output:

```
f1, 1, one
f1, 2, two
f1, 3, three
f2, 1, one
f2, 2, two
f2, 3, three
f3, 1, one
f3, 2, two
f3, 3, three
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to save it to a csv file, see if this helps. You can use `OrderedDict` if the order matters.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv


file_list = ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
inner_dict = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}
outer_dict = OrderedDict()

for f in file_list:
    outer_dict[f] = inner_dict

rows = []
for i,k in outer_dict.items():
    for m,n in k.items():
        rows += [[str(x) for x in [i, m, n]]]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    _csv = csv.writer(f, escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    [_csv.writerow(row) for row in rows]
```

The test.csv file would look so:

```
f1,1,one
f1,2,two
f1,3,three
f2,1,one
f2,2,two
f2,3,three
f3,1,one
f3,2,two
f3,3,three
```