# Python sets in dictionary not consistant sort behaviour

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I created a dictionary of sets in Python:

```
graph = {'A': {'B', 'C'},
     'B': {'D', 'E'},
     'C': {'F','A'}}

print(graph['A'])
print(graph['B'])
print(graph['C'])
```

However the order that elements are printed differ everytime I execute my code!

```
{'B', 'C'}
{'E', 'D'}
{'F', 'A'}
```

and next time:

```
{'B', 'C'}
{'D', 'E'}
{'A', 'F'}
```

What causes this inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: A better link to answer the question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956313/why-is-dictionary-ordering-non-deterministic

Comment: @MarkRansom added it to the list of duplicates

Comment: @vaultah thanks. I could have done it myself if I had remembered the ability to edit duplicate link lists.